# How to custom bean field by jackson serializer without annotation by @JsonSerialize(using = JsonCustomerSerialize.class)

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Now I have bean like this:

```
@Data
public class JsonSerialModel {
    public JsonSerialModel(String name, Date birthday,List<String> names) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.name = name;
        this.names = names;
    }

    private String name;
    @JsonSerialize(using = JsonCustomerSerialize.class)
    private Date birthday;
    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = JsonCustomerContentSerialize.class)
    private List<String> names;
}
```

by this  I can custom field serialize

but I wanna use custom annotation  like   @Coustom(value="AES") so I can 
get  value AES and serialize my filed by AES or other value,

so  how to implement this by using jackson

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get answer from jackson source code test case

Implement  ContextualSerializer interface  then use BeanProperty